# How Do Chrome Apps/Extensions View Search/Browsing History if there is no permission for it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

There are several apps/extensions that work with search/browsing history, here are just two:

1) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/better-history/obciceimmggglbmelaidpjlmodcebijb?hl=en

2) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-timeline/gjhpcfomcckgcaniehfgakaddjgncpeb?hl=en

However, unless I'm missing something neither apps nor extensions have a permission for retrieving the full search or browsing history, only for deleting it, querying for a specific website, or adding urls to the history that are accessed after the app/extension is installed.

Please see my post immediately before this one if you'd like links to the permissions pages for apps and extensions.

How can I get access to all search/browsing history with an app or extension as the two examples above appear to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example one** uses the explicit `"history"` permission, available to extensions.

This generates an informative warning *"Read and change your browser history on all signed-in devices"*.

It can retrieve the actual history information with the [corresponding API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history#method-search):

```js
chrome.history.search({text: ""}, function(visits) {
  // The last 100 visits will be here. Filter by date to get more.
});
```

> `text`
>   A free-text query to the history service. Leave empty to retrieve all pages.

**Example two** does not show data from actual Chrome history. Instead, it has the following permissions permissions:

- `"tabs"` permission, allowing it to catch all URL updates via `onUpdated` and similar events for tabs.
- A content script that injects into all pages, giving access to content of pages.
- Just in case, a full `"<all_urls>"` access to do anything with any page.

All of this results in the suitably scary *"Read and change all your data on the webpages you visit"* warning.

However, if you just install it, it will show a blank history. That's because it cannot access the history store without permission, and instead builds its own history database